# Mlapi RPC Attributes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, methods, rpc

I was following the tutorial about 'Mlapi' in Unity. In the tutorial, I have a question when I studying about RPCs.

So the question I have is

1. When I make a method with the `ServerRpc` attribute how does the 'Mlapi' handle that method? According to 'Mlapi' documentation, All I have to do to call the `ServerRpc` function is just making a direct function call with parameters. But what happens when I call the method marked by `ServerRpc`? What I did was just calling the method marked by the `ServerRpc` attribute. But how the 'Mlapi' get method marked by the `ServerRpc` attribute or other Rpc attribute I wrote? And how does the 'Mlapi' call the method from the client and execute it on another machine?

Comment: Is your target to build something similar yourself? Or just pure interest?

Comment: I lately built a custom local Network Multiuser without any attributes where you can just invoke **any** method on remote devices .. basically using Reflection. It is therefore a little bit slower. The attiebutes are basicallytwo things: An obfuscation level to make things easier for you and since the available methods are pre registered with a certain index it is faster to call them

Comment: It was just pure interest but now I want to study the RPC. If it is okay can you explain more about the below comment? About how RPC wrapper intercepted method call?

Comment: RPC means nothing but "Remote Procedure Call" .. basically it means nothing more then "Call a method/execute some code on a remote device". There are thousand ways how this can be done e.g. via TCP or UDP etc ... the wrapper is not RPC specific but is a general c# thing ;) If you want a good example for how to built an interceptor itself look at [Transform setter interceptor](https://github.com/handzlikchris/Unity.TransformSetterInterceptor) where someone has built a post-compilation interceptor for the `Transform` component .. basically something like that is also done by the RPC attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RPC is a well-documented concept. You should look up some references.  The RPC client "marshals" your parameters into a format that can be transmitted via network, and sends them with information that tells the other side which function you are calling.  The RPC server on the other end "unmarshals" those parameters back into binary structures and calls the function.  It then "marshals" the return value and ships it back to the client, where it gets "unmarshalled" back to you.

The RPC server knows which services it is offering, so it's not just calling random functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Then making the direct function call with parameters to invoke the RPC function is not actually call the function? It looks like I'm calling the function but it doesn't execute on my local machine. How that works? How do they call the function on my machine but don't execute it on my machine even the calling the function looks like just normally call the function?
Also, are there some references about RPC implementation? I can't find good references.

Comment: What happens is that as a post-compilation step all methods with according attribute(s) are collected (e.g. via Reflection) and a wrapper is built around them. So whenever you call the method the actual call is intercepted by the RPC wrapper. Then basically since all methods are prestored in the same compilation order every device "knows" which method has which index and which index calls which method .. so the RPC basically only sends to the other devices: "Call the method with index X and pass in the following parameters Y and Z

Comment: There is a "stub" library linked in to your local executable with the same signature as the routine you want to call.  Your local function call executes that stub function, which takes the necessary steps to ship the parameters to the server machine.

Comment: @derHugo  Thanks for the reply! Answer for your above comment, it was just pure interest. But now I want to study it. So if it is okay can you explain to me more about the above comment? About how RPC wrapper intercepted method call and are there some references about RPC that can help me? And thanks for 'Time Roberts' answering me again!

Comment: Here are some good web pages about RPC: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/how-rpc-works  https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node33.html